# "Lonely Integer" Python implementation

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-2.x

Problem Statement

> There are N integers in an array A. All but one integer occur in pairs. Your task is to find the number that occurs only once.

Input Format

> The first line of the input contains an integer N, indicating the number of integers. The next line contains N space-separated integers that form the array A.

Constraints

> \$1≤N<100\$
>
> \$N % 2 = 1\$ (N is an odd number)
>
> \$0≤A_{i}≤100,∀i∈[1,N]\$

Output Format

> Output S, the number that occurs only once.

Solution

```
#!/usr/bin/py
from collections import Counter

def histogram(ary):
    """ Creates a histogram of the given array.
    Args:
        ary: The array.
    Returns:
        The dictionary with key as number and value as count.
    """
    return Counter(ary)

def lonelyinteger(ary):
    """ Finds the unique element in the array.
    Args:
        ary: The input array.
    Returns:
        Number or None
    """
    for frequency in histogram(ary).items():
        if frequency[1] == 1:
            return frequency[0]
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = int(raw_input())
    b = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(" "))
    print lonelyinteger(b)
```

The solution works perfectly fine. But in the process of learning problem-solving, I am interested in a few things:

- I don't think that the information like N is odd or maximum limit of 100 is related to my solution. Is there some optimizations I am missing?
- What about the space complexity? I think it's \$O(N)\$ + size of the histogram.
- Runtime seems linear i.e \$O(N)\$.

Solution 2

It includes the factors like why N should be odd.

Example: `1 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 2 ^ 3`

```
#!/usr/bin/py
def lonelyinteger(a):
    res = 0
    for each in a:
        res ^= each
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = input()
    b = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(" "))
    print lonelyinteger(b)
```

Comment: You are right on all 3 counts. However, the problem has an \$O(1)\$ space-wise solution. Hint: think of `xor`.

Comment: @vnp, for `solution 2` yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few quick comments:

- Indeed, your solution doesn’t require \$N\$ to be odd. You’ve solved the slightly more general problem of finding a lonely integer in an array where every other element occurs at least twice, but could occur more often than that.

  Likewise, the restriction that \$N \leq 100\$ isn’t used, but I can’t think of how that could be used in a solution.
- I don’t know why you’ve defined a histogram() function, when you could swap it out for Counter(). That will make your code a little easier to read, because when I read Counter(), I immediately know what it does; if I see histogram() then I have to check I’ve understood the definition.
- When you iterate over the histogram, you should use `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`; in Python 2.7 the latter is slower and more memory-expensive.
- You don’t need an explicit `return None`; Python will automatically return None if it drops out the end of a function.
- Rather than iterating over the tuples in `Counter(array).items()` and picking out the element/frequency by numeric index, it would be better to use tuple unpacking in the for loop:

  ```
  for elem, frequency in histogram(ary).items():
      if frequency == 1:
          return elem
  ```

  You could also just use the `most_common()` method on Counter(), and take the last element of that – but at that point you’re barely doing any work, so that might not be in the spirit of the problem.